# Stop execution of Ruby script

Tags: ruby, exit, abort

Is there a method like `exit` or `die` in PHP which stops the execution of a Ruby script?

Answer (score 105):

Either [`abort`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-abort) or [`exit`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-exit) will help.

Comment: Like @webwurst says in the other answer, use abort to specify a failed end to the script, and exit for a successful end.

Answer (score 89):

[`abort`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-abort) is an alias for `Kernel.exit(false)` which terminates execution immediately.

[`exit`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-exit) is an alias for `Kernel.exit(true)` and raises the [`SystemExit`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/SystemExit.html) exception, that may be caught. Also [`at_exit`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-at_exit) functions and [`finalizers`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/ObjectSpace.html#method-c-define_finalizer) are run before termination.

Answer (score 8):

`abort` can still hang if there's threads that are waiting. If you *really* want to terminate immediately try:

```
Process.kill 9, Process.pid
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI for ruby on rails, you can simply use this gem
`shutup`,
in the rails directory run this command in the bash terminal

`gem install shutup`

it will find the PID of rails server and kill it.

and also you can do it with `lsof -wi tcp:3000` in case you didnt start the server on another port otherwise you should change the port `3000`